# link qr code to Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an idea for my final project, which is I will make an android application name books translations using `QR` code.I will pick one books and I plan to put each `QR` code in each page of book. If user scan the `QR` code,it will show the translations of that page.i will stored the translations in database. I intended to use a stand alone database. I will use `sqlite` database using `Oracle`. so how can I link `QR` code with the `sqlite`.

Is my method right? if wrong I hope someone can give or guide me to the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the QR codes so that they contain unique data(ID - such as a long) then link these to the Primary Key of your database and for each ID insert the translation of the page you know it belongs to.

Comment: thanks for feedback @Catalina , but i still can't see how to do it or how it work, can you give more explanation or if you have some tutorials or sample code can you pass it to me so i can see it more clearly,